# How to print long double number in xinu?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers, long-double, xinu

Function `sqrtl` doesn't work here, also the `printf` of `long double` prints `f` for all given numbers:

```
#include <conf.h>
#include <kernel.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

long double sqrtn; 
unsigned long int n;    

void xmain() {
    unsigned long int n;   
    printf("Enter unsigned long integer:\n"); 
    scanf("%lu", &n); 
    sqrtn = sqrtl(long double)n);
    printf("\nsqrtn=%Lf\n", sqrtn); 
} /* main */
```

Comment: Are you compiling a program for userland or a kernel module? Can you print the value of `sizeof(long double)`? It should be 12 bytes. Also are you running on an old 3B2 box or an intel CPU?

Comment: Another hint: do you link your program with `-lm` to add floating point support for `printf`?

Comment: More information about Xinu: https://xinu.cs.purdue.edu/ What does "Function `sqrtl` doesn't work here" mean? If you got an error message, please include it in your question. You have mismatched parentheses in your program. Please copy-and-paste your actual code.

Comment: With a conforming implementation, `printf("%Lf\n", sqrtn)` should work correctly. There are probably some things that the Xinu implementation doesn't support.

Comment: 1) To investigate such problems, avoid `"%f"` and friends, use `"%g"`.  2) report data entered and exact output seen.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the Xinu source code for x86 from https://xinu.cs.purdue.edu/files/Xinu-code-Galileo.tar.gz .

Looking at the implementation for `printf` (`lib/printf.c` `lib/doprnt.c`), as far as I can tell it simply doesn't support length modifiers. That means that, for example, this:

```
long int n = 42;
printf("%ld\n", n);
```

wouldn't work.  I suggest trying that on your system.

This is not a conforming C implementation (and it's probably not intended to be).

It does appear to support most of the standard conversion specifiers (`"%d"`, `"%u"`, `"%x"`, `"%f"`, etc.).

If you want to print a `long double` value, I think the best you can do is either convert it to `double` and use `"%f"` (which could lose range and/or precision) or write your own code to convert a `long double` value to a string. (Or run you code on a different system).

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this, I've only examined the source code, and only for the x86 version of the system.

Comment: *write your own code to convert a `long double` value to a string*... Not for the faint of heart. So ride, boldly ride, to the end of the rainbow, Ride, boldly ride, till you find El Dorado

Comment: @chqrlie Writing your own code could include copying an open source implementation.

Answer (score -2):

I was worried about long double won't print.
i wrote a small test and found out that my MAC wanted to have **%Lf** or **%Le**.
it seems that capital L must be used.

Comment: the OP already used `%Lf`. And mac has nothing to do with Xinu